# The Axiom of Choice is equivalent to the proposition that every infinte cardinal is an aleph

Tags: set-theory

According to [this](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Gillman544-553.pdf) article, the Axiom of Choice is equivalent to the proposition that every infinte cardinal is an aleph and it can be proved by just looking at the definitions. However, the article is somewhat intuitive in that a cardinal number is not specified exactly.

I want to show this is true formally, which means formal definitions. If I define a cardinal as it is done [here](https://www.ii.com/cardinal-numbers/#:%7E:text=Here%20is%20the%20definition%20used,are%20equinumerous%20to%20x%2C%20otherwise.), that is

> The cardinal (or cardinality) of $x$, denoted card($x$), is: the least
> ordinal equinumerous to $x$, if $x$ is well-orderable, and the set of
> all sets $y$ of least rank which are equinumerous to $x$, otherwise.

And say $\alpha$ is a cardinal $\iff$ $\alpha$ is the cardinality of some set and $\alpha$ is an aleph $\iff$ $\alpha$ is the cardinality of an infinte well-orderable set. Under these common definitions, can we now show the captioned result?

If we assume AC and $\alpha$ is an infinite cardinal, then from our definition of cardinal, $\alpha=$ card($x$) for some $x$. And due to AC, $x$ is well-orderable and so by definition of cardinality of a set, $\alpha$ is the least ordinal equinumerous with $x$ and so $x$ is also infinite. Hence $\alpha$ is the cardinality of an infinte well-orderable set and hence an aleph.

Now assume every infinite cardinal is an aleph. If $x$ is a finite set then it is well-orderable. Let $x$ be an infinte set that is not well-orderable. Then card($x$) is the set of all sets $y$ of least rank which are equinumerous to $x$. And we can show (*) that card($x$) is infinte. Hence card($x$) is an aleph, a contradiction (e.g. an aleph is an ordinal so doesnt contain sets all of the same equinumerosity). Hence every set is well orderable and we have the AC.

Is this a valid proof and is this how the the expanded definition of cardinality in ZF is supposed to be used? (Mixing the initial ordinal definition of a well-orderable cardinal with the Scott's Trick definition of non well-orderable set doesn't seem right - it seems the result is true by coincidence rather than an underlying reason).

I think I would prefer the statement that the Axiom of Choice is equivalent to each infinite set is equinumerous with an aleph.

(*) Note reproduced here for brevity - Edit - Actually my proof doesnt work as it relies on AC. Is it true that card($x$) is infinite when $x$ is infinite and not well orderable?

Comment: The usual proof strategy is to note $\mathsf{AC}$ is equivalent to all sets being well-orderable, which is equivalent to all infinite sets being equinumerous to an aleph.

Comment: Yes, showing AC is equivalent to all infinite sets are equinumerous to an aleph is very straightforwards. But that's not the same as showing every infinte cardinal is an aleph, when we formally define a "cardinal".  I think this article is subtly assuming that a set is equinumerous with its cardinal number, which doesnt hold under the formal definition.

Comment: There is no need to dwell on the technical definition of cardinal numbers. All we need to know is that every set $x$ has a cardinal number $\operatorname{card}x$; that $\operatorname{card}x=\operatorname{card}y$ if and only if there is a bijection between $x$ and $y$; and that $\aleph_\alpha$ is defined as the cardinal number of the initial ordinal $\omega_\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking on board bof's comment, we can show every infinite cardinal is an aleph implies the AC without going down the route of looking at the literal definition of the cardinality of a set that is not well-orderable (other than to show the below). From our (technical) definition of cardinality we can prove, card$(x)=$card$(y) \iff x \approx y.$ And this applies if $x,y$ are well-orderable or not well-orderable.

Suppose $x$ is an infinite set that is not well-orderable. Suppose card($x$) is finite. Then card($x) \approx n$ for some natural number $n$. And as $n$ is a well-ordered cardinal card$(n)=n$ and so card$(x)=$card$(n)$ and so $x \approx n$. But $x$ is infinte, a contradiction. Hence card($x$) is infinite and therefore by our assumption an aleph, say $\aleph_\alpha$. And again as $\aleph_\alpha$ is a well-ordered cardinal, the cardinality of $\aleph_\alpha$ is $\aleph_\alpha$. Hence card$(x)=$card$(\aleph_\alpha$). And so $x \approx \aleph_\alpha$ Hence $x$ is well-orderable and we have the AC.