Infinite cardinals are exactly the aleph numbers
I am trying to show that:
$\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal if and only if there is some ordinal $\xi$ such that $\kappa = \aleph_{\xi}$.
I can show the backwards direction fine. The forwards direction is a not so clear to me. I know that every infinite cardinal is a limit ordinal, but I can't quite see for which ordinal $\xi$ the claim is true. Any guidance would be great, thanks!

Probably a duplicate. Related questions can be found via search. For example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809457

Anyway, here is a Hint (which I will not post as an answer since I think this question is a duplicate). Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal. Show that the set of ordinals $\alpha$ with $\kappa \leq \aleph_{\alpha}$ must be non-empty (in fact, it contains ...). Define $\xi$ as the smallest such ordinal. Finish.

Oh yes I see, $\beta \leq \aleph_{\beta}$ for all ordinals $\beta$ and then the rest follows nicely, thanks!
